# IdentityServer4 with LDAP/AD authentication without UI

Tags: asp.net-core, ldap, identityserver4

I'm currently working on a project where I'm trying to set up a service based on IdentityServer4 (https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4) that authenticates users by querying a local Active Directory via LDAP.

To achieve that, I also included the IdentityServer4.LdapExtension (https://github.com/Nordes/IdentityServer4.LdapExtension) in my project. The working example from the repository works fine (https://github.com/Nordes/IdentityServer4.LdapExtension/tree/master/Sample/IdentityServer) - but the custom logic is part of the UI, and I need my service to operate without any UI.

Simply adding

```
.AddLdapUsers<ActiveDirectoryAppUser>(Conf.GetSection("ldap"), UserStore.InMemory)
```

as described in the documentation does not change the request pipeline, as the provided login/validation methods are never executed - they are only triggered with calls from the UI (AccountController). However, as I said, I don't want to integrate any UI in this service and rather use the interface which the Token-Endpoint already provides (POST request with client_id and client_secret, response with JWT).

Is there a way to integrate LDAP authentication without rewriting big parts that work out-of-the-box as desired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question it sounds like you already have a `username` and `password`. Note `client_id` != `username` and `client_secret` != `password`. `client_id` is the identity for a client application.

The grant type you are trying to use is called [Resource Owner Password](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/topics/grant_types.html) when using the authorize endpoint or [password](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/endpoints/token.html) when using the token endpoint.
This grant type is used to support legacy systems and is not recommended for new development.

The code that you want to executed to authenticate a user is in [LdapUserResourceOwnerPasswordValidator.cs](https://github.com/Nordes/IdentityServer4.LdapExtension/blob/master/IdentityServer.LdapExtension/Extensions/LdapUserResourceOwnerPasswordValidator.cs) and it should be executed if you pass the correct parameters to the token endpoint:

> POST /connect/token
>
> ```
> client_id=yourclientid&
> client_secret=yourclientsecret&
> grant_type=password&
> username=yourusername&password=yourusernamespassword
> ```

See token endpoint documentation: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/endpoints/token.html

You can use [Identity Model](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel2/tree/release/src/IdentityModel) to help you make the token request:

```
var response = await client.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordTokenRequest
{
    Address = "https://demo.identityserver.io/connect/token",

    ClientId = "yourclientid",
    ClientSecret = "yourclientsecret",
    UserName = "yourusername",
    Password = "yourusernamespassword"
});
```

This is documented here https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/token.html

Comment: Thank you very much! The hint that client_id/secret are NOT the username/password really helped....when I send a request using grant_type "password" and I provide client_id, client_secret, username and password as described, it queries the Active Directory as desired.